# Problem in a form validation using jQuery, work for another form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, validation

I need help because i use jQuery for validating 2 form, for the first form this jQuery is working nicely, but for the second form it doesn't work because it keep submitting blank space. This is my jQuery code

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";


/*==================================================================
[ Validate ]*/
var input = $('.validate-input .input100');
// var input2 = $('.validate-angkatan .input100');

$('.validate-form').on('submit',function(){
    var check = true;

    for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if(validate(input[i]) == false){
            showValidate(input[i]);
            check=false;
        }
    }
    

    return check;
});



$('.validate-form .input100').each(function(){
    $(this).focus(function(){
       hideValidate(this);
    });
});

function validate (input) {
    if($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
        if($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if($(input).val().trim() == ''){
            return false;
        }
    }
}


function showValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
}

function hideValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
}
})(jQuery);
```

this is the first form which is working nicely with the validation above

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form ml-5" action="/DatabaseAlumni/login/auth" method="post">
                <span class="login100-form-title">
                    Login Alumni
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <span class="symbol-input100">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <span class="symbol-input100">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Lupa
                    </span>
                    <a class="txt2" href="#">
                        Password?
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                    <a class="txt2" href="/DatabaseAlumni/register">
                        Buat Akun
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is the second form, it keeps submitting blank space

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form ml-5" action="/DatabaseAlumni/register/createacc" method="post">
                <span class="login100-form-title">
                    Daftar Akun
                </span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Isi NPM">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="npm" placeholder="NPM">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Isi dengan nama lengkap">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Isi dengan angkatan">
                            <?php $a = date("Y"); ?>
                            <input class="input100" type="number" name="angkatan" placeholder="Angkatan" min="1960" max=<?= $a - 4; ?>>
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <div class="wrap-input100 validate-angkatan" data-validate="Isi dengan angkatan">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="nama" id="angkatan" placeholder="Angkatan" autocomplete="off">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>

                        </div> -->


                        <div class="wrap-input100">
                            <div class="row mt-4 ml-4">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Laki-laki">
                                    <label class="ml-1" for="male">Laki-laki</label><br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Perempuan">
                                    <label class="ml-1" for="female">Perempuan</label><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">



                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Masukkan Email dengan benar">
                            <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password Wajib Diisi">
                            <input id="password" class="input100" type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="check();">
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Masukkan kembali Password">
                            <input id="confirm_password" class="input100" type="password" name="pw2" placeholder="Konfirmasi Password" onkeyup="check();">
                            <label><span id="message"></span></label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                        Daftar
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                    <a class="txt2" href="/DatabaseAlumni/login">
                        Sudah memiliki akun? Masuk
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I try the pause on breakpoint in the debug feature in my browser and setting a breakpoint at

```
check=false;
```

in the jQuery. When i try submitting the first form with empty inputs, i got a pause. But for the second form i got nothing. I don't understand because I'm using the same structure for both form, including the classes and the div's.

Comment: Is your 2nd form created dynamically after the page has loaded (eg via an ajax call or in a modal dialog)?  You could try: `$(document).on('submit', '.validate-form', function()`

Comment: Are both forms on the same page?  Or on different pages?  if on different pages double-check you've included the .js.  Are there any console errors?

Comment: Use the appropriate input type for email and year and use the required attribute. Good turtorial: https://web.dev/sign-in-form-best-practices/ - Also password confirmation is nothing but a pain, let browser autosuggest a strong password

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, I checked the console logs and found that i had a typo in my include for the jquery file